# What tool should I use for drawing 2D OpenGL shapes?

Tags: 2d, opengl-es, art

I'm working on a very simple OpenGL ES 2.0 game, and I'm not sure what tool to use to create the vertex data I need. My first thought was adobe illustrator, but I can't seem to find any info on how to convert an .ai file to vertices. I'm only going to be using very simple 2D shapes so I wonder if I need to use a 3d modelling program?

How is this typically done, when you are working with 2D non-sprite shapes?

Comment: Why can you not create a quad and add a texture to it?

Answer (score 4):

If shapes are really complicated, I would recommend 3D modelling software (for example Blender, which is freeware). When you will be loading data, you can just throw away one coordinate. You can for example use front orthogonal view and then discard z-coordinate.

Such software also allow to export data to some graphic format, like OBJ or PLY. There is a lot of loaders for them already written.

Answer (score 1):

You could try importing files in the [SVG file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). It's not super simple, but there are a fair number of tools that can output the format (such as [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) on Windows). The [fog framework](http://code.google.com/p/fog/) includes a SVG loader, and you can find a few other examples by poking around Google.

Answer (score 0):

If the shapes are really simple (eg circles, triangles, etc), you can just generate the vertices using simple functions without going through any graphics or modeling program.

Comment: They're simple, but not that simple...

Comment: Think something along the lines of a vector lunar lander game.